# Query the network range for the particular OID and print result

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, networking, snmp

this bash script query the network range for the particular OID and return results.

```
#!/bin/bash

# snmpget command query the network range for target OIDs

for (( i=254; $i; i=$i-1 )) do host=10.250.53.$i; snmpget -v 2c -c public -t 0.5 -r 1 $host iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0; done; read -p 'press Enter to continue...'
```

How to modify it to return result only if this OID (sysDescr) contains a specific SW_REV string? I.e. `SW_REV: r4000-d7000r1037-993021u;` If different version, then ignore address.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a command to filter `snmpget`'s output. For example with `grep`:

```
for (( i=254; $i; i=$i-1 )) do
    host=10.250.53.$i
    snmpget -v 2c -c public -t 0.5 -r 1 $host iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 | grep r4000-d7000r1037-993021u
done
read -p 'press Enter to continue...'
```

If the goal is to retrieve only the IP address (I don't know what's the output of `snmpget`) then you can test if the string matched (using `grep -q`) and display only the IP address if it did:

```
for (( i=254; $i; i=$i-1 )) do
    host=10.250.53.$i
    if snmpget -v 2c -c public -t 0.5 -r 1 $host iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 | grep -q r4000-d7000r1037-993021u; then
        echo $host
    fi
done
read -p 'press Enter to continue...'
```